# Browser location share in windows mobile

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a mobile optimised version of our website. When user get prompted with share location dialogue box one of our user accidental pressed No button. He refreshed so many times and even cleared maps and internet explorer browser history. He even rebooted(classic windows thing) the phone, but never get the dialogue box reappear.

Our application needs locations otherwise it will display a error message saying "We are sorry we need your location" with a refresh button by the side.

We tried the same thing on iPhone, android. Everything prompts back the user but the windows mobile.

Please let me know is there any way i can share my location again in my second chance in internet explorer?

For example, if you go to http://maps.google.com in your windows mobile and press no when it prompts for the location share. How do I later make my phone to share the location using any settings for that website.

Do I need to insert any code in my Webpage?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows Phone** (which is different from Windows Mobile) the use of location by the browser (based on the prompt you describe) is controlled via system application settings.

From the app list, select `settings`
Swipe over to the `applications` item
Select `Internet Explorer`
Toggle the "Allow access to my location" switch (make sure it's on)

Now revisit the website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. But this is already On. I disallowed only for a website. but couldnt get back the same popup when you refresh. iPhone and android gives the pop up back once you refresh but not internet explorer in Windows Phone 7

Comment: Yes, I think basically windows phone itself has bug in that I think. If you try maps.google.com and say no when it prompts for share location. It will never ask you again no matter what you do...